# Positive-definite 2x2 matrix invariant under conjugation with W -> W unitary?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory, matrix-decomposition

I have the following problem for complex matrices:
$G$ is a positive-definite, hermitian 2x2-matrix and $W$ an invertible 2x2 matrix. Moreover, $WGW^\dagger = G$ holds. Does this imply that $W$ is unitary (with respect to the standard scalar product)?

(Edit: The answer is NO. See the counter example below!)
At first sight, it seemed obvious to me that the answer is YES. However, I still could not prove it. One should probably use the fact that $G = UDU^\dagger$ for unitary $U$ and a positive-definite diagonal matrix $D$.  Furthermore, $\text{det}(WGW^\dagger) = \text{det}(W) \text{det}(G) \text{det}(W^\dagger) = \text{det}(G)$ and combined with $\text{det}(G) >0$ this yields $|\text{det}(G)| = 1$.

This is indication for the fact that $W$ could be unitary, but it's of course not enough.

Any help is welcome!
Thanks a lot!

Cheers
Qwerkopf

PS: What would the answer be in case of dxd-matrices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write that $G = MM^\dagger$ (e.g. via the Cholesky decomposition).  Then we have
$$
WGW^\dagger = G \iff\\
(WM)(WM)^\dagger = MM^\dagger \iff\\
(M^{-1}WM)(M^{-1}WM)^\dagger = I
$$
That is, this is equivalent to saying that $M^{-1}WM$ is unitary, which is to say that $W = MUM^{-1}$ for some unitary $U$.

That is, in general: all we can know is that $M$ is *similar* to a unitary matrix (so it is diagonalizable with the correct eigenvalues, but won't necessarily satisfy $WW^\dagger = I$).

**Counterexample:**  Take 
$$
M = \pmatrix{1&1\\0&1},  \quad G = MM^\dagger = \pmatrix{2&1\\1&1}\\
$$ 
Now, take
$$
W = M \pmatrix{1\\&-1}M^{-1} = \pmatrix{1&-2\\0&-1}
$$

Comment: Very elegant and a nice way to find a counter example. Problem solved. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: No problem.  The same idea applies for $d \times d$ matrices, of course.

Answer (score 1):

This implies that $W$ is unitary with respect to the scalar product defined by $G$, i.e. $\langle v,w \rangle = v^T G \overline{w}.$

This is because the adjoint of $W$ is $G^{-1} \overline{W^T} G$: You can verify $$\langle Wv, w \rangle = v^T W^T G \overline{w} = v^T G\overline{G^{-1} \overline{W^T} G w} = \langle v, G^{-1} \overline{W^T} G w \rangle.$$

Typically this does not mean that $W$ will be unitary with respect to the Euclidean scalar product though.

Comment: Thanks for this answer!
I was thinking about the Euclidean (standard) scalar product (I added it now in the question).